# Java problem inheriting interface implementation when extending a class

Tags: java

I am struggling to get an interface implementation to be inherited in another class:

I have a generic class that requires compareTo to be implemented. The class is called GenericList and is implemented as:

```
public class GenericList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private T[] items;
    private int count;
    public GenericList() {
        items = (T[]) new Comparable[10];
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

I have a User class that implements compareTo:

```
public class User implements Comparable<User> {
    private String email;

    public User(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User o) {
        return (email.compareTo(o.email));

    }
}
```

I have no problem creating a GenericList of Users:

```
var users = new GenericList<User>();
```

If I create a class that extends User and try to create a generic list of that type, I get an error. I have created a class called Instructor:

```
public class Instructor extends User{
    public Instructor(String email){
        super(email);
    }
}
```

If I create a generic list using that class:

```
var instructors = new GenericList<Instructor>();
```

I get an error:

```
Type parameter 'com.martin.Instructor' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable<com.martin.Instructor>'
```

Shouldn't it use the inherited compareTo method?

I've tried lots of different ways but I can't get GenericList to use an inherited class like this.

Thanks

Comment: Instructor inherits `compareTo(User)`. The interface requires `compareTo(Instructor)`.

Comment: To clarify, `Instructor` needs to implement `int compareTo(Instructor)` even if it just delegates to its superclass.

Comment: youcan try to declare `public class GenericList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    private T[] items;`

Comment: Also, that cast in the GenericList constructor skates by now with type erasure, but would break if we ever get reified generics.

Comment: Martin... think about the previous two comments logically. `Instructor` can have additional fields that are not accounted for when you compare just a generic `User`. That's why `Instructor` must have a `compareTo()` method.

Comment: Thanks to all for your advise. I got it working with `public class GenericList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `public class GenericList<T extends Comparable<T>>`

When you declare `GenericList<Instructor>`, then the above declaration replaces `T` with `Instructor`. So now it says that `Instructor` must extend (or implement, really) `Comparable<Instructor>`. The problem is that `Instructor` extends `User` which implements `Comparable<User>` but doesn't implement `Comparable<Instructor>`.

So the problem is well before trying to find the inherited `compareTo()` method. One way to fix the immediate compiler error is to change the `GenericList` declaration:

```
public class GenericList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

This uses a type capture on the `Comparable` interface.

Now fair warning, I have check that this change will compile [here](https://replit.com/@codeguru/VigorousBestAdvance), but otherwise I have not tested it because your question doesn't provide any usages of `GenericList` once you create it.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the advice - worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

The overall logic seems to be correct: User and Comperable are the supertypes of the Instructor class, i.e. instance of Instructor can represent them both. But here's a catch:

```
var ints1 = (Comparable<Instructor>) new Instructor("name"); // this line will not compline
var ints2 = (Comparable<User>) new Instructor("name"); // no errors here
```

The first line will cause a compilation error because there's no implementation of the **Comparable<Instructor>** in the inheritance chain of the Instructor class, but there's an implementation of the **Comparable<User>** which is the class User itself. And hence the signature of compareTo() method that Instructor class inherits will be compareTo(User user).

A quick reminder: generics are invariant, i.e. to a variable of type List<Object> we can assign only List<Object>, not List<Person> or List<Cat>. Similarly types **Comparable<User>** and **Comparable<Instructor>** are not comparable with each other regardless of the fact that User is a super-type of Instructor. That's what is called invariance and the main purpose of it is to enforce type-safety.

As the conscience of this, it isn't possible to coerce Instructor object to **Comparable<Instructor>** type.

A possible remedy is to implement Comparable in the Instructor class, it will be useful only if Instructor defines some own properties that establish uniqueness of its instances, or  [change the declaration of generic type as already shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70841265/17949945)